# How to get data and time from the date object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

How can we get date and time from the date object.
So if we have a date object such as Date 2099-09-06T06:30:00.000Z , how can we get date and time as different values from it.
I am using ExtJs, so if we can do in Extjs too would be great.

Comment: RTD: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in JavaScript in the following way:

```js
var dateOriginal = new Date("2099-09-06T06:30:00.000Z");
var date = dateOriginal.toLocaleDateString();
var time = dateOriginal.toLocaleTimeString();
console.log('Date: ' +date);
console.log('Time: ' +time);
```

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJs you can use the [Ext.Date](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Date.html) singleton to parse the date string to a date object. Then use the methods of the date object, see the [Date docu on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
datetimeObj   = Ext.Date.parse('2099-09-06T06:30:00.000Z', 'c');
datePart      = datetimeObj.toDateString();
datePartLocal = datetimeObj.toLocaleDateString();
timePartLocalTimezone = datetimeObj.toLocaleTimeString('arab', {timeZone: 'UTC'});
timePartUTC   = datetime.toLocaleTimeString('arab', {timeZone: 'UTC'});
```